# AdminLTE collapsed boxes by default

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

AdminLTE is based on Bootstrap: https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE

**Live Preview:** http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview/

But I'm unsure as to how to make the collapsable boxes collapsed by default.

I'm assuming since it is built on Bootstrap, this should be rather straightforward. I've tried fellow implementations such as setting the id to "collapsedOne" and attempting to treat the divs as accordions, but to no avail.

On the AdminLTE/app.js ~line 45 there is code that implements slide up/slide down to collapse boxes. Ideally, what we'd want is to have the boxes be in the "slide up" state by default with the class "collapsed-box" so that when the icon is clicked, it executes "slide down".

```
/*     
 * Add collapse and remove events to boxes
 */
$("[data-widget='collapse']").click(function() {
    //Find the box parent        
    var box = $(this).parents(".box").first();
    //Find the body and the footer
    var bf = box.find(".box-body, .box-footer");
    if (!box.hasClass("collapsed-box")) {
        box.addClass("collapsed-box");
        bf.slideUp();
    } else {
        box.removeClass("collapsed-box");
        bf.slideDown();
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 53):

When the page loads in its initial state, why not just add the `collapsed-box` class to box element?

The below will render in the collapsed state and function without modifying AdminLTE:

```
    <!-- Default box -->
    <div class="box box-solid collapsed-box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Default Solid Box</h3>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;" class="box-body">
            Box class: <code>.box.box-solid</code>
            <p>bla bla</p>
        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: But how to handle the plus and minus signals, @user4036441? With this solution the box is collapsed when page is loaded, but the signal that we see is the minus signal.

Comment: @AloysiadeArgenteuil simply change the icon to ```fa-plus``` instead of ```fa-minus```. This is the initial icon, AdminLTE's javascript should handle reversal after that.

Comment: Thanks for such a simple solution.

Answer (score 12):

`$("[data-widget='collapse']").click()` Add that to a JavaScript file that runs at the bottom

Comment: I updated the problem with an edit. Calling simple "collapse" doesn't work.

Comment: I understand that this collapses my boxes after the page loads, however I would like the boxes to be collapsed by default.

Answer (score 9):

Here are the steps:

1. Change the minus icon to plus .
2. Add explicit style "display:none" to box-body
3. Add the class "collapsed-box" to the box

Answer (score 9):

For those who are using **AdminLTE 2.1.1**

just simply add `sidebar-collapse` class on the `<BODY>`

Before:

```
 <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
```

After:

```
 <body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">
```

Answer (score 9):

An open box:
`<div class="box">`

A collapsed box:
`<div class="box collapsed-box">`

And then ofcourse change the icon on the button

Answer (score 8):

In Admin LTE 3 collapse by default by using the class `collapsed-card` on the main card.

Like this

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="card collapsed-card">
   <div class="card-header" >
     <h3 class="card-title">Expandable</h3>
     <div class="card-tools">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
       </button>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body" >
     The body of the card
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You should change the icon to a fas fa-plus then the initial box starts with a plus

Answer (score 5):

```
$("[data-widget='collapse']").click(function() {
    //Find the box parent........
    var box = $(this).parents(".box").first();
    //Find the body and the footer
    var bf = box.find(".box-body, .box-footer");
    if (!$(this).children().hasClass("fa-plus")) {.
        $(this).children(".fa-minus").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        bf.slideUp();
    } else {
        //Convert plus into minus
        $(this).children(".fa-plus").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        bf.slideDown();
    }
});
```

and use in section div

Answer (score 1):

for one specify div

```
$(function() { $('your-button-id').click(); })
```

for all

```
  $(function() { $("[data-widget='collapse']").click(); })
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add "collapsed-box" to the box and change this:

```
<button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

This should work for me

Answer (score 0):

The correct tested Steps which worked for me are :

1. Add explicit style "display:none" to box-body
2. You are done :)

   ```
           <div class="box ">
                       <div class="box-header with-border bg-yellow">
                         <h3 class="box-title">Box Title Here</h3>
                         <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                           <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                           <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                         </div>
                       </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                       <div class="box-body" style="display: none;">
                         <div class="table-responsive">

                               <!--Your content here -->

                         </div><!-- /.table-responsive -->
                       </div><!-- /.box-body -->

           </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box box-default collapsed-box">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">Expandable</h3>
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div><!-- /.box-tools -->
  </div><!-- /.box-header -->
  <div class="box-body">
    The body of the box
  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
</div><!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: Hey some `html`!  Do you have any explanation or commentary on the code?

Answer (score 0):

This soluction worked for me:

I added "collapse-left" class for the menu and added the "strech" class for the main content.

I use the version 1 for the AdminLTE. It is divided in aside class="left-side" for the left menu and aside class="right-side" for the main content.

So, this is the final code:

```
<aside class="left-side collapse-left"> 
    <!-- put the left menu here --> 
</aside>
<aside class="right-side strech"> 
    <!-- put the main content here -->
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the boxWidget object:

```
setInitialCollapseStatus: function (container) {
        var _this = this;
        var collapsedBoxes = container.find('.box.collapsed-box .btn-box-tool > i');

        collapsedBoxes.each(function (index) {
            var box = $(this);
            //Convert minus into plus
            box
                .removeClass(_this.icons.collapse)
                .addClass(_this.icons.open);

        });

    }
```

and called it during initializiation:

```
activate: function (_box) {
        var _this = this;
        if (!_box) {
            _box = document; // activate all boxes per default
        }
        //Listen for collapse event triggers
        $(_box).on('click', _this.selectors.collapse, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            _this.collapse($(this));
        });

        //Listen for remove event triggers
        $(_box).on('click', _this.selectors.remove, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            _this.remove($(this));
        });

        // Set initial collapseStatus
        _this.setInitialCollapseStatus($(_box));
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css classes into body tag in the index.html file:

> **sidebar-closed sidebar-collapse**

```
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini sidebar-closed sidebar-collapse layout-fixed layout-navbar-fixed layout-footer-fixed">
```

Answer (score 0):

With Adminlte 3:

1. Card Parent add ID: `<div class="card card-default" id="a">`
2. Change `<i class="fas fa-minus"></i>` TO => `<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>`
3. Add Display:none `<div class="card-body" style="display:none">`
4. Add jquery `$('#a').CardWidget('toggle');`